# Post a local file in a form of $_FILES in php

Tags: php

I wanna post a local file to an identified url in $_FILES variable. Just the same thing as received via a form after submitting. How can I do that?

Comment: I have already cropped and uploaded an image to my server. no I want to post a copy to another script on a particular address to be saved by that script. The receiver script can be in any language.

Comment: You must show the efforts here , so others can help you where you are `actually` stuck up. Since you didn't you could see the answers.. they are far **too broad**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use cURL or etc.
For example see http://www.php-guru.in/2013/upload-files-using-php-curl/

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding use CURL to post a local file using PHP to another url
Try testing it with upload.php

**upload.php**

```
<?php
/* http://google.com/upload.php may be like this you can create file on localhost
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
*/
?>
```

*Code to post file is*

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/test.png');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://google.com/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($ch);
?>
```